# How to store a text in mysql separated by a comma

Tags: php, mysql

i have a query that in table replies i have to add few words seperated by commas

Like a user said 
How are you

so it should store the txt like 'how,are,you'

...
and how will i fetch the the text from the cell

Basically it should be like

User submits a reply to a bot in which

the bot will give the reply on the bases of the words ...

Comment: Why would you store the values separated by comma? Why not fetch the string and break it up afterwards?

Comment: The only answer I could give here is to literally build the whole thing myself and send you the code. That won't be happening. Maybe provide more information of what you have tried, where you are at with the project etc. Even a single line of code would be a plus here

Answer (score 1):

You can use str_replace so you can replace all spaces with commas.
Something like

```
str_replace(' ', ',', $userstring)
```